# ContextStartedEvent not firing in custom listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to hook into the creation of the context using a custom application listener like this

```
@Component
public class ContextStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Context started"); // this never happens
    }
}
```

But the `onApplicationEvent` method never fires. If I use a different event such as `ContextRefreshedEvent` then it works just fine, but I need to hook into before it is created. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**[Edit]**

Editing answer adding more info because of the downvote.

The reason why you are not getting a callback by the listener is because you are not explicitly calling the **LifeCycle** `start()` method ([JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html#start--)).

This cascades down to your **ApplicationContext** normally via the **AbstractApplicationContext** on in Spring Boot case via the **ConfigurableApplicationContext**.

Example of working code below demonstrating how your callback would work (just explicitly call the start() method)

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        applicationContext.start();
    }

    @Component
    class ContextStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Context started");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I suggested below the `ContextRefreshedEvent` callback instead is because behind the scenes the `refresh()` code is getting invoked.

If you drill down the `SpringApplication#run()` method [you'll eventually see it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L327).

Again here's a working example of how this would work using the `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    class ContextStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Context refreshed");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**[Before Edit]**

Change the Generic type to `ContextRefreshedEvent` instead and then it should work.

For more details read [this article from the Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2). Just to quote the part about the `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

> [..]This allows MyListener to be notified when the context has *refreshed*
>   and one can use that to run arbitrary code when the application
>   context has fully started.[..]

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Phil Webb (from the Spring team) on [a similar issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27945) on their GitHub:

> The `ContextStartedEvent` is being published, but it's before any beans are registered so it's already happened by the time your `ContextStartedListener` `@Component` is created. You can use `SpringApplication.addListeners` if you want to listen for early events.